# Do Office 365 Add-Ins require specific Internet Explorer security settings?

Tags: office365, office-js

While trying to deploy an office 365 add-in at one of our customers we encountered the following issue:

The add-in loads inside Word Desktop and Word Online. When one of the buttons is pressed, an error message apprears stating:
"Sorry, we couldn't load the app because your browser version is not supported. Click here for a list of supported browser versions."

The relevant versions:
IE 11 update 42
Word O365 ProPlus 1705 (Current Channel)

The Internet Explorer version was fully up-to-date, and we have seen it working for that version of IE. It could be that there are some security settings that are preventing Word from loading the Add-In, I cannot find any information about this, however.

Does anyone know if there are settings that could result in this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**
This is the error message that appears when one of the buttons tries to open a TaskPane. Other buttons that execute some JavaScript, will show an error modal dialog with more or less the same text. I am sorry that this error message is Dutch, but I haven't found a way to reproduce on an English system, yet.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: I a screenshot of the error message to the original post.

Comment: This is generic error message which doesn't mean anything: "This plug-in can not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click Refresh to retry.". I assume you don't have any issues with SSL certificate for your application, cause you said it works somewhere else. Are you using properly obtained SSL? Some companies have very tight group policies and may not allow "active scripting", would you check this with your customer? Play with security level of IE, see if it set to "custom", if so try to re-set it to, for example, "medium".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error while trying to use an Office add-in. I had to reinstall Internet Explorer 11 on the Windows 10 PC.